# implode() MySql Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I am trying to implode some variables and insert them into a MySql database, but for some reason it is not working. I have been trying for hours and I''m just not sure what I'm doing wrong.
If you can help it would be much appreciated.

```
$AddressString = "address1,address2,address3,address5,postcode";

$AddressSplit = explode( ",", $AddressString );    //split the address string
$StringLength = count( $AddressSplit ) - 1;
$s = 0;      //trim any white spaces from the address string
while ( $s < count( $AddressSplit ) ) {
  $AddressSplit[$s] = trim( $AddressSplit[$s] );
  $s++;
}

//Create the Values to insert into DB
$MysqlValues = implode( "','", $AddressSplit );
$MysqlValues = "'$MysqlValues'";
$NumberVals = count( $AddressSplit );

$t = 1;
while ( $t < $NumberVals ) {
  $ad[$i] = "add$i";
  $t++;
}
$TableNames = implode( ", ", $ad );

mysql_query( "INSERT INTO pstc_add_main (" . $TableNames . ",add10,date)
                                VALUES (" . $MysqlValues . ",'$cdate')" );
}
```

Comment: `echo` your full query just before calling `mysql_query`.

Comment: $MysqlValues = implode("','", $AddressSplit); should have been, $MysqlValues = implode(",", $AddressSplit);

Comment: Is your input string properly escaped/filtered? Otherwise you're just looking for problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you start making the field names 1 based, your are one field short!
In the end you must end with a equal number of fields and values.

Try this:

```
$t = 0;
while ( $t < $NumberVals ) {
  $ad[$i] = "add$i";
  $t++;
}
```

Or, if you do not want the first field to be "add", change it like this:

```
$t = 1;
while ( $t <= $NumberVals ) {
  $ad[$i] = "add$i";
  $t++;
}
```

Of course, it would have been a easy test to do:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pstc_add_main (" . $TableNames . ",add10,date)
                           VALUES (" . $MysqlValues . ",'$cdate')";
var_dump($sql);
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested,

I doubt you change,

```
   $MysqlValues = implode("','", $AddressSplit);
```

to

```
  $MysqlValues = implode(",", $AddressSplit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$MysqlValues = implode( ",", $AddressSplit );
```

and try to edit the code like

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO pstc_add_main (".$TableNames." ,add10,date)
                            VALUES (" . $MysqlValues . ",$cdate)" );
```